# How to find out SQL Server *.ndf file contents

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to remove some old files from a production DB, these files are parts of partitioned table. So, the steps were following - I deleted data that theoretically were kept there by partition function (all data from 2007).

Then I merge partition function for that year:

```
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION pfPeriod() MERGE RANGE (2007);
```

Then, I wanted to remove file and filegroup:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydatabase REMOVE FILE tbProperty2007
ALTER DATABASE mydatabase REMOVE FILEGROUP fgProperty2007
```

- all by the book.

I'm getting the error:

> *The file 'tbProperty2007' cannot be removed because it is not empty.
>
>   The filegroup 'fgProperty2007' cannot be removed because it is not empty.*

I've done this procedure before (for 2005, 2006) and the reason why files wouldn't remove (for another table) was the index - it was kept in one of the files (I accidentally created index in the partitions of the table). After I recreated index in another filegroup - I could delete file and filegroup without any trouble.

Anyway, this time I recreated indexes in another filegroups, and still - I can't delete the file and filegroup.

So, can anybody give me an idea how can I see the contents of the *.ndf file, or why the file wouldn't delete ? please )

P.S. May be it's a bug of sql server 2012 - I was able to delete files on the sql server 2005, but I can't do it on 2012.

Comment: I gave up and did the shrinkfile with EMPTYFILE option, it helped
'DBCC SHRINKFILE('tbProperty2007', EMPTYFILE)'
Then I was able to delete file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a query like this:

```
select t.name as table_name,
    i.name as index_name,
    ds.name as data_space_name,
    ds.type_desc,
    ps.name as partition_scheme_name
from sys.tables t
join sys.indexes i on t.object_id = i.object_id
join sys.data_spaces ds on i.data_space_id = ds.data_space_id
left join sys.partition_schemes ps on ps.data_space_id = ds.data_space_id;
```

This will show you which indexes are hosted on which [data space](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190289%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). You can see if you have a non-partitioned index or table in the filegroup `fgProperty2007`.

You can also use a query like following to figure out if any partitioning scheme still uses the filegroup:

```
select ps.name as partition_scheme_name,
    dds.destination_id as parition_number,
    d.name as filegroup_name
from sys.partition_schemes ps
join sys.destination_data_spaces dds
    on ps.data_space_id = dds.partition_scheme_id
join sys.data_spaces d
    on d.data_space_id = dds.data_space_id;
```

Comment: Thank you very much - these queries are really what I've been looking for. Unfortunately, it didn't help - both scripts results don't have any mention of fgProperty2007, but I still can't delete it - I'm getting the same errors for the file and filegroup (

Comment: If the filegroup is 'in use' then the file is in use too, so is normal to get the same error for both.

Comment: Yep, I agree - the file has to be deleted first. 
But it's not normal to have empty file and not be able to delete it.

Comment: My query joins `sys.tables` so it will only show user tables. Can you try with joining sys.objects and check if some internal table is not in this FG? Could be a queue, a change tracking table or similar. also, I assume you have the required privileges to view *all* objects in the database (ie. is not a user table in the FG which you're not allowed to see due to low privileges).

Comment: I have the administrator privileges, I see all the tables - it wasn't a problem. I just gave up and used shrinkfile with emptyfile option - it helped, and I'm happy. I marked your comment as answer, because my question was about those queries, and you really helped me with my paranoia, thank you.